# aix ksh : how to quit the vi command line editor wirthout actually executing the command?

Tags: ksh

In ksh, when you are in vi mode, you can invoke the vi editor by using ESC+v.

Then, vi is launched, and you can use it to edit the command you were working on.

The problem is that, whatever how you quit the editor (:q!, ...), it seems the command will always be executed. Is there a trick for this not to happen ?

My only solution so far is to delete the whole command then exit with :q!

Answer (score 0):

When your command is a oneliner, you can `I`nsert a `#` at the first position.
When you have more lines, you do not want to comment all lines.
Enter `return` above the first line (use `O`) and the rest will be ignored. Do not use exit, than you will exit your shell.
EDIT:
As @Henk pointed out in the comments, the trick with `return` will fail with a real ksh shell. I tested `set -o vi` in `bash` and things are different there.

Comment: `return` drops me from the shell

Comment: @Henk What do you get when you enter `return` from the commandline? I get after `$ return` the response `bash: return: can only 'return' from a function or sourced script`

Comment: I'm running the latest AT&T [tag:ksh].  Your answer may not be valid for this  question.  Quoting the [posix description of return](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#return): *The return utility shall cause the shell to stop executing the current function or dot script. If the shell is not currently executing a function or dot script, the results are unspecified.*

Answer (score 0):

Just typing `ggdGZZ` would be quicker, but here are two options:

### Option 1, quotes

Insert `: '` at the top and a single quote `'` at the end:

```
: '
more 
than 
one 
line
'
```

Swap single quotes for double quotes if necessary.

### Option 2, force a syntax error

Insert `:` followed by an unset variable reference, triggering a syntax error:

```
: ${nil:?}
more 
than 
one 
line

"/tmp/ast38.kia" [converted] 5L, 33C written
: ${nil:?}
more 
than 
one 
line
/bin/ksh: hist: line 1: nil: parameter not set
$
```